What happened to the lifeboats in Star Trek: First Contact?
In the movie Star Trek: First Contact, just before Picard went to face the Borg Queen he orders to the Enterprise crew to abandon ship. We see a dozen or so lifeboats leave the ship and head to Earth.
What happened to these lifeboats? Were they left on Earth? Or were they secretly recovered without the Vulcans sensing them leave the planet?
And bonus question. Where did Lily's lifeboat land such that she could join the first contact party?

The official novelisation is quite vague on the subject. It just states that the ship has been returned to 'normal' by the time Picard and Riker are beamed up. This presumably includes surreptitiously beaming the pods and crew back on board without the Vulcans noticing.

Aboard the Enterprise-E, now gratifyingly back to normal, Picard looked upon his bridge and his senior crew—Will, Geordi, Beverly, Deanna, Data—and the on-loan Worf—with newfound appreciation. He felt appreciation, too, for the future that awaited them, and all who had helped bring it to pass.
“Report,” he said, with unalloyed pleasure.
“The moon’s gravitational field obscured our warp signature,” Worf responded. “The Vulcans did not detect us.”

Given the relatively primitive nature of the Vulcan ship it was, we can assume, not a significant challenge to do this right under their pointy ears.

As to your bonus question, Picard was keen for Lily to see first contact take place. There appears to have been a few hours elapse between the warp flight, the landing of the Phoenix and the arrival of the Vulcans. This is more than enough time for the Enterprise to beam Picard down to the silo and beam Lily back to his location, regardless of where she landed.

The moon's gravitational field obscured the warp signature from Enterprise's powerful engine, but the earth's gravitational field did not obscure the warp signature from the Phoenix's primitive engine.

@DanielWagner - Presumably it also warped back.

Nice. The other explanation I could come up with (with no in-universe evidence so far as I know) is that maybe the thing that makes the better warp drives better is that more of their power goes into locomotion and less into the signature, making their signatures harder to detect.

@DanielWagner - The Vulcan ship (named in the EU novels as the Vesaya) is a very typical example of a pre-Federation vessel. The Enterprise has extensive databases covering its capabilities and limitations. They can easily mask their signature from its sensors using this knowledge. Worf isn't in the slightest bit concerned about having been detected.
